# Using args in a phython function that does not multiply the values

Tags: python, args

I what to apply thins function to every value in this list but it just prints out the list 2 times instead of multiplying the values of the list.

```
 def test(*args):
     val=args*2
     return val

 val=[1,2.3,4,5]
 hello=test(val)
 print(hello)
```

Comment: you have to use `for`-loop or list comprehension `val = [x*2 for x in args]`

Comment: `args` is a `tuple`.  Like lists and strings `tuple*2` is replication, not numeric multiplication.  When in doubt, verify the `type` of an object, and then look up its methods.  e.g. `print(type(args))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your function as

```
def test(*args):
  return [x*2 for x in args]
```

if you want to call it as

```
hello = test(*val)
```

or as

```
def test(args):
   return [x*2 for x in args]
```

if you want to call it as

```
hello = test(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your args is a tuple of list,
use:

```
def test(*args):
    val=[i*2 for i in args[0]]
    return val

val=[1,2.3,4,5] 
hello=test(val) 
print(hello)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

Replace only one line(i.e.`val=args*2`) of your code:

```
val = [i*2 for j in args for i in j]
```

Full code:

```
def test(*args):
    val = [i*2 for j in args for i in j]
    return val
val = [1, 2.3, 4, 5]
hello = test(val)
print(hello)
```

This solution will work on any number of list you pass.